# How can I kill a whole process tree with Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, process, solaris, kill

What's the best way to kill a process and all its child processes from a Perl script? It should run at least under Linux and Solaris, and not require installation of any additional packages.

My guess would be to get a list of all processes and their parents by parsing files in /proc or by parsing the output of `ps` (neither of which seems portable between Linux and Solaris); and then killing all processes in the tree (which seems prone to race conditions).

I could live with the race conditions in this particular case, but how do I portably get the process list?

Answer (score 9):

If you can live with killing a process group, you can use the following:

```
kill -$signum, $pgid;
```

where `$signum` is the signal number, and `$pgid` is the process group ID. However, signal numbers aren't very portable, in which case you can (on some platforms; read `perlfunc` for explanation) do the following (to send `SIGTERM`, for example):

```
kill 'TERM', -$pgid;
```

Comment: Which processes do belong to a process group? I'm using IPC::Open3 to start a process (which on Solaris runs the command inside sh -c), and I want to kill the sh and my actual command and all further subprocesses. What if the process group contains even the Perl interpreter? Can't that happen?

Comment: As long as you're not using SIGKILL, you can make your Perl program ignore the signal you're sending. Read perlipc (search for "process group").

Answer (score 8):

CPAN has an answer. Yes, I know you did not want to install additional modules, but at least you can look at the implementation and see what they are doing...

https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::ProcessTable

Answer (score 0):

I adapted and hacked "rkill" to do the job, it was easy.

https://gitlab.com/pslist/pslist/blob/master/pslist

This is part of "pslist" package in e.g. ubuntu.